# Passing variables to map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps, dictionary

I'm trying to send a few longitude and latitude variables to a function that will then generate a Google Map.

Starting with a datatable that retrieves various information stored in a database, I'm using data-attributes to store the lng and lat for each record.  When a record is selected, a modal opens and the map is displayed.

I was able to get the map to display with default lng and lat points.  But now I need to create a new map every time a record is selected.

Starting with the onclick event that triggers the modal to open (shortened as much as possible):

```
$('#example1').on('click', 'tr > td > a.actionMatch', function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();

  var actimpbill = $(this).attr('data-actimpbill'); // random record info
  var actramplat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-actramplat')); // first lat
  var actramplng = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-actramplng')); // first lng
  var actdellat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-actdellat')); // second lat
  var actdellng = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-actdellng')); // second lng

  // my map was opening in a grey box. this next piece of code fixed that
  $("#actionMatchbackModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  });

  initMap(actramplat, actramplng, actdellat, actdellng); // my attempt to call a function and the variables to it

  $('#actionMatchbackModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
});
```

Here is the function that sets the map. This is located outside of the initial onclick event that opens the modal (I'm not sure if that's a problem).  This is where I'm trying to pass the variables that I created inside the onclick event:

```
function initMap(actramplat, actramplng, actdellat, actdellng)
{
  // map options
  var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {actramplat, actramplng}
  }

  // new map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

  // add marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:{actdellat, actdellng},
    map: map
  });
}
```

I am probably butchering the function call.  The function once housed the default lat and lng numbers and I was able to properly generate a map.

### Edit

I just checked the console, and I am getting these errors:

```
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

### Edit

I just added parseFloat to the variables to ensure they are not strings, but still no success.

### Edit

Here is what the data-attributes look like:

```
<a href="#" class="actionMatch" id="actionMatch" 
data-toggle="modal" data-actimpbill="xxxxxxxx" 
data-actramplat="39.11" data-actramplng="-94.63" 
data-actdellat="39.03" data-actdellng="-96.83"
data-actreclat="39.84" data-actreclng="-96.65"
rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Action Matchback"></a>
```

You can see the actramplat, actramplng, actdellat, actdellng in the A tag above.

Comment: Can you please clarify what error you're getting, and at what point it's happening?

Comment: Also, if you question whether the variables are being passed to the function, have you tried using console.log() to inspect the values inside initMap?

Comment: I just edited the question with some console errors.

Comment: You're passing strings which should be LatLng objects (or number?).

Comment: So, console.log the reclat, reclng, dellat, dellng in the first line of the initMap function to see the values.

Comment: Inside the initMap function I did this: console.log('this is dellat ' + dellat); and got this result: this is dellat 39.11

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a number?  It's possible it's a string.

Comment: Maybe it is indeed a string.  I'll check...

Comment: No luck.  I added parseFloat to the variables to ensure they were not strings, but no luck.

Comment: Can you give us some example values for those variables?

Comment: Adjusted my code.

Comment: I wish people would explain the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at their [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers), they expect lat/long values to be provided as an object literal that looks like this: `var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};`

So you need to call it like this:

```
// map options
  var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: dellat, lng: dellng}
  }

  // new map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

  // add marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:{lat: reclat, lng: reclng},
    map: map
  });
```

Comment: YES!!!  I think that did the trick.  Still having issues centering, but the map now displays with the marker.  Thank you, sir.